# Getting only first array from foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in making concept of ajax...

I am posting data from ajax but it only post the first array from foreach loop.

code ----

```
<tbody id="presentor">
<?php if(!empty($data)):?>
<?php $counter = '0'; foreach ($data as $lead):?>
   <?php $prospect_type = $this->admin_model->getData('prospect_type',$lead->prospect_type);?>
   <?php $language = $this>admin_model->getData('language',$lead>language);?>
   <?php $source = $this->admin_model->getData('source',$lead->source);?>
   <?php $location = $this->admin_model->getData('location',$lead>location);>
   <?php $requirement = $this->admin_model->getData('requirement',$lead->requirement);?>
   <?php $lead_type = $this>admin_model->getData('lead_type',$lead>lead_type);?>
   <?php $lead_status = $this->admin_model->getData('status',$lead->lead_status);?>

      <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;"><?php echo ++$counter;?></td>
      <td id="lead_date"><?php echo $lead->leadDate;?></td>
      <td id="first_name"><?php echo $lead->first_name;?></td>
      <td id="last_name"><?php echo $lead->last_name;?></td>
      <td id="prospect_type"><?php echo $prospect_type[0]->prospect_type;?></td>
      <td id="number"><?php echo $lead->number;?></td>
      <td id="email_id"><?php echo $lead->email_id;?></td>
      <td id="language"><?php echo $language[0]->language_name;?></td>
      <td id="source"><?php echo $source[0]->source_name;?></td>
      <td id="location"><?php echo $location[0]->location_name;?></td>
      <td id="requirement"><?php echo $requirement[0]->requirement;?></td>
      <td id="lead_type"><?php echo $lead_type[0]->lead_type;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $lead->executive_comment;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $lead->admin_remark;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $lead_status[0]->status;?></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;">
      <a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>dashboard/edit_Data/<?php echo $lead->id;?>/add_lead/"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      | <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="deleteLead('<?php echo $base_url;?>dashboard/delete_Data/<?php echo $lead->id;?>/lead/');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      | <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="lead_id" data-custom-value="<?php echo $lead->id;?>"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
       </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
</tbody>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" id="leadId">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Select Employee</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="item form-group">
                <div for="name">
                    <span class="required">Assigned To</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php $user = $this->admin_model->getData('user');?>
                    <select class="form-control" name="user" id="assign_user">
                        <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
                        <?php foreach ($user as $row): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->first_name . " " . $row->last_name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a id="assignResult" class="btn btn-primary modal-toggle" style="background-color: #000;border-color: #000;">Assign</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also i use html model for calling user id and name below is code

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content" id="leadId">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Select Employee</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="item form-group">
     <div for="name">
      <span class="required">Assigned To</span>
     </div>
    <div>
    <?php $user = $this->admin_model->getData('user');?>
      <select class="form-control" name="user" id="assign_user">
        <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
          <?php foreach ($user as $row): ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->first_name . " " . $row->last_name; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <a id="assignResult" class="btn btn-primary modal-toggle"style="background-color: #000;border-color: #000;">Assign</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

jquery and ajax file here ----

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#assignResult").click(function () {

        var lead_date = $( '#lead_date' ).text();
        var lead_id = $( '#lead_id' ).data("custom-value");
        var assign_userId =  $( "#assign_user option:selected" ).val();
        var first_name =  $( "#first_name" ).text();
        var last_name =  $( "#last_name" ).text();
        var prospect_type =  $( "#prospect_type" ).text();
        var number =  $( "#number" ).text();
        var email_id =  $( "#email_id" ).text();
        var language =  $( "#language" ).text();
        var source =  $( "#source" ).text();
        var location =  $( "#location" ).text();
        var requirement =  $( "#requirement" ).text();
        var lead_type =  $( "#lead_type" ).text();      

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $base_url?>dashboard/send_leads',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                lead_date : lead_date,
                lead_id : JSON.stringify(lead_id),
                assign_user: assign_userId,
                first_name : first_name,
                last_name : last_name,
                prospect_type : prospect_type,
                number : number,
                email_id : email_id,
                language : language,
                source : source,
                location : location,
                requirement : requirement,
                lead_type : lead_type,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert("There is an error with AJAX!");
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

this is what my array look like

```
 Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [leadDate] => 2018-08-01
        [first_name] => Rishab
        [last_name] => Patel
        [prospect_type] => 1
        [number] => 9988665523
        [email_id] => rishab@gmail.com
        [language] => 2
        [source] => 1
        [location] => 2
        [requirement] => 1
        [lead_type] => 3
        [executive_comment] => Call him
        [admin_remark] => good
        [lead_status] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [leadDate] => 2018-08-09
        [first_name] => Ajay
        [last_name] => Patel
        [prospect_type] => 4
        [number] => 1232426225
        [email_id] => ajaypatel@gmail.com
        [language] => 2
        [source] => 2
        [location] => 1
        [requirement] => 1
        [lead_type] => 3
        [executive_comment] => Call him
        [admin_remark] => good
        [lead_status] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [leadDate] => 2018-08-13
        [first_name] => praney
        [last_name] => panday
        [prospect_type] => 3
        [number] => 7845123265
        [email_id] => praneypanday@gmail.com
        [language] => 2
        [source] => 1
        [location] => 2
        [requirement] => 1
        [lead_type] => 2
        [executive_comment] => Call him
        [admin_remark] => good
        [lead_status] => 1
    )
)
```

But when i post it through ajax it only post [0] array, then i try to alert every var but it shows the same [0] array value.

any help or i am doing it wrong

thanks in advance....

Comment: You seem to have a couple of places where you have something like `admin_model>getData` (i.e. without the `-`).

Comment: it's because you have the same ids multiple times. That won't work. How should ajax know which row to take/send?

Comment: a tip: get away from storing (and then sending) data in html (you do that in <td>s). Keep your data as js objects/arrays. Why do you need to send all that (unmodified) back to the server anyway? Wouldn't the selected user id and lead id be enough?

Comment: thanks for your reply guys but where i am using multiple id's @Jeff

Comment: hey @Jeff where am i using multiple id's, i didn't see any multiple id's and as i said i only get [0] array value so it only showing [0] array value of lead id.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are assigning the same HTML id to every row of the same "*type*" in your table.

Let me explain : if you put a

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
```

into a loop, every cell

```
<td id="lead_date"></td>
```

will have the id `#lead_date`.

Since element IDs should be unique within the entire document, the resulting HTML is not valid.

The jQuery script assigns the value of `#lead_date` to an internal var

```
var lead_date = $( '#lead_date' ).text();
```

but if you have more than one field with id `#lead_date`, which one will be assigned? Only the first one.

This applies to every field of your html table at the moment, and this is why only the first array is posted.

To fix your problem, first of all do not duplicate HTML id.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but didn't understand where you are saying to use name attribute and name attribute is not valid in <td> @ZePollaBot